# Ipad simulators for website testing deliver inaccurate results! Are there any better ones than Ipad peek?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4

I tried tesing my website for Ipad on `Ipad peek`(an online simulator) but it actually gives very incorrect results. Tried several others too but none with accurate results.  Are there any better ones out there where I can even chose different iOS versions to check against?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Safari.app from the iOS Simulator that ships with Xcode 4.2, which is available from the Mac App Store. This of course requires that you own a Mac.